# Adding not-null column to large table SQL Server 2012 behaves differently on different servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-performance, alter-table

In SQL Server 2008/2012, adding a null column to a large table (with default null) is more or less instant.

```
ALTER TABLE TableWithManyRows
    ADD TestNull INT NULL;
```

In SQL Server 2012, this should also be the case for not-null columns being set to a default value - see http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/

The following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE TableWithManyRows
    ADD TestWithValues INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES;
```

run more or less instantly on my local machine, but very slow on the production database server.

Both are running SQL Server 2012. Running the "Null" version is instant on both, it's just the non-null case where I am seeing differences.

Is there a configuration option that could influence this? Any other suggestions on how I can track down the difference?

**Solution** (in case someone doesn't spot it in the comments below)

I was confused because locally I have the developer edition, which behaves like the Enterprise edition. The production server didn't have the enterprise edition.

Comment: How big is dataset on your machine vs server? What is total row count?

Comment: Approx 500k rows in both cases.

Comment: If other processes are hitting the table in production at the same time your are trying to alter the table that would greatly effect performance. For something this big I would make it into a job that would run once after-hours during slowest time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE TableWithManyRows
    ADD TestNull INT NULL;
```

Does nothing to the table's records

```
ALTER TABLE TableWithManyRows
    ADD TestWithValues INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES;
```

Updates every record for that column to a value of 0. With a large amount of data this will take time.

Not a lot you can do about that if that is your business rule.

Comment: That's not true for SQL-Server 2012 - see the link in the question. (It was the case for 2008).

As I said, I am seeing different behaviour on different servers with the exact same statement.

Comment: and you are sure neither of these two caveats are broken "In the case when the newly added column increases the maximum possible row size over the 8060 bytes limit the column cannot be added online. And is an Enterprise Edition only feature. ". it seems obvious to me from the diagnosis, SS is indeed trying to update every row

Comment: Jenson-button-event - Thanks, you found it. Locally I have the developer edition, which has all the features of the Enterprise edition. The server doesn't have Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that could cause this.  Performing this action requires the table to be locked for the updates.  It also has to update each row of existing data.  If you have many rows of data (as production databases typically have more than your dev copy) it will take a longer time.  Also, if the server is under a high load and many people are using the database and table, this can also cause some performance degradation while the systems waits to get an exclusive lock on the table and/or rows of data to update the schema and set the value in each existing row.

Comment: Dev copy is using a table with 500k rows. If I force all records to update (e.g. calling Update TableWithManyRows Set TestWithValues = 1 ) then that takes a noticable amount of time on my dev machine. This isn't due to a difference in table size between dev and prod.